# Stop loading site to display a message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I wanna show my visitors a message before they enter the site, and then allow them to continue to the main site using a button. I don't wanna move the main sites location either.

Similar to this:

```
<script>
    function continue() { /* function to continue loading site */ }
</script>

<p>This is a message. <button onclick="continue();">I agree</button></p>

<script>
    //stop loading what's below when someone enters the site, and display only the message
</script>

<html>
<body>
    <p>This is my main site with a lot of content.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't just cover the main site, I don't want any of it's functions to run when the visitor is reading the message.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your most efficient option would be to cover the page and have a button fade the div out to display the rest of the content. What is it specifically that doesn't let you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop loading page by JS. In some situation JS can stop render page. But it still readable by machine/show-source.

If you don't want cover site, you can hide some elements by `style="display:none"`.

If page must be unreadable by machine you must realize this on server side:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(!empty($_POST['policy'])) $_SESSION['accepted_policy'] = true; 
if(empty($_SESSION['accepted_policy'])) { 
?><form action="?" method="post"> 
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="policy"> I've accepted ...<br /> 
<input type="submit" > </form>
<?php die(); 
} ?>
normal page
```

If you don't want execute any JS before `continue()` you can run it from this function instead `$.ready()`